# Powershell R Script Remote Execution

Tags: r, powershell, powershell-remoting

I´ll try to keep my Question Simple.
I have an R script which when executed localy works perfectly, 
now if i try to launch it remotly with an powershell script with the invoke-command, i´ll get an error message from R(Cant allocate Vector of Size 126.6 MB).
The R script remotly finds all filepaths needed and have the same credentials as the local execution, but i get the R Error Message.

Any ideas if there are any restrictions from remote executions?
I´ll also tried to use an extra .bat file which executes the R Script, but i get the same R Error.

Kr
Johann

Comment: Might help if you provide the script?

Comment: How do you try to excute it? Could you provide a code snippet please

Comment: Hi this is my execution script: Invoke-Command -ComputerName Remote -FilePath script.ps1 -ArgumentList{args} -Credential $Cred")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was that the r Script needed more then 1 GB Ram and the original settings of remoting for powershell is only 1 GB. I followed the instructions in  this blog https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/07/30/learn-how-to-configure-powershell-memory/
and could get my script running from remote.

Answer (score -2):

This means your remote system does not have enough memory available.

Comment: Instead of downvoting please provide a reason why my answer is incorrect.

Comment: My remote System have enough memory, as i said if i connect per rdp on my remote system en execute that script it will run. So i dont think its because of the memory. btw i did not downvote your comment